# How to center a triangle in the exact center of a div

Tags: html, geometry, center, margin

I am trying to center a triangle in the exact center of a div, but i cant do it.
It positions itself in the middle of the div but just on horizontal alignment not vertical 
.I made the `margin: 0 auto;` but still doesn't work.I have also tried `display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;` on the inner div giving a `margin: 0 auto;` to outside div ,yet nothing.I also tried with `display: inline-block;` and no result.  And i don't know why! Does someone have any idea?

My simple code is :
[jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/XUxEC/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few options.

My favourite is to give outer div an absolute position, give the inner one a relative position and then use top:50% to position vertically. You also need to add a negative margin of half the height of the triangle because top:50% will centre the top of the triangle not the middle of it.

```
#main_content {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;

    position: absolute;
}


#container {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 25px 43.3px 25px 0;
    border-color: transparent #007bff transparent transparent;

    position: relative;
    top:50%;
    margin:  -21.65px auto; //Half the height of your triangle
}
```

Comment: Thank you this pretty much did the job but what if my main_content div has width and height in % ?  JSFIDDLE doesnt format good with %

Comment: Just tried it out with % width and heights in fiddle - works fine. Also works fine in the browser straight. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Well this is embarrassing , i forgot to give the height % :/ sorry for  the disturb , and thank you for your detailed reply :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set display:table-cell of main_content and then use vertical-align: middle;

```
#main_content {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```